# UICollectionView header view like table view header

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to create UICollectionView header view like UITableView headerView? I mean header view for whole collection view, not the repeated one for each section.

If that's impossible, then how could I add outlets to section view subviews from Storyboard?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eventually I put UICollectionView in UITableViewCell and added some code to calculate cell height.